# How can I avoid the black screen on boot with GMA500 graphics?

Tags: 12.04, gma500

Ubuntu 12.04 was released today, but it still can't boot normally with GMA500 graphics :(. It's a black screen and i need to go into text mode via Ctrl-Alt-F1 and restart desktop manager via "sudo service lightdm restart".

Is it any way to avoid this restarts every time OS boots?

Comment: I think the OP's question was how to boot a GMA500 system into a graphical environment without console juggling on boot, not how to arrive at the admin console without pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should add 'console=tty1' to grub options.

To do that, run `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
find the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`, and change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty1"
```

Lastly, update grub with `sudo update-grub`.

- [How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter)

Answer (score -1):

The added line didn't work for me. Here's what did (from: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsboAlternatives)...

**Getting 1366x768 resolution**

Create file /etc/grub.d/01_915resolution with lines

echo insmod 915resolution
echo 915resolution 58 1366 768 32
and execute:

chmod +x /etc/grub.d/01_915resolution
In file /etc/default/grub, assign value 1366x768x32 to variables GRUB_GFXMODE and GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX:

GRUB_GFXMODE=1366x768x32
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1366x768x32

Execute:

sudo update-grub
reboot, now you have 1366x768 resolution.

===

I already had that resolution, but with the added commands above I can now **see** the screen too.

Comment: That's funny considering the 915resolution is not in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The above don't change anything. Also keep in mind not all Poulsbo systems have 1366x768 resolution when changing things in /etc/default/grub.